# connecting a 2-wire (red, blue) ceiling light to a 3-wire (red, black, green) ceiling power source

Tags: wiring

In Sydney Australia, how do I connect a 2-wire (red, blue) ceiling light to a 3-wire (red, black, green) ceiling power source?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture of  the box and the fixture might help.

Answer (score 1):

See [Australia: Which wire is hot / active and which is neutral?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/114077/australia-which-wire-is-hot-active-and-which-is-neutral) for some more details, but basically:

- Hot: Red -> Red
- Neutral: Blue -> Black
- Ground: Green

Typically, if you have a fixture that does not have a separate ground wire then there will be a screw attachment point on the fixture to connect the ground wire.

Answer (score 1):

Australia's historical color for **neutral is black**.  (Following UK's lead for black=neutral red=hot, a convention still used most places for DC power).

The new 4-continent standard for **neutral is light blue**.

So it's easy to see by context that your legacy Australian wiring has black as neutral, and your modern world-market lamp has blue as neutral.  Join those.

Grounds are worldwide standard as green, yellow/green or bare wire.

That leaves two remaining wires that must be the hots.